# Android Studio - weightSum

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_weight="2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/centerText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:text="HALLO ALLE"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/centerText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Btn 1"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hi everybody, this is my code and I have a question about this I set a `weightSum` in the first `LinearLayout` I set the `weightSum` of 10, which the `RelativeLayout` has 2/10 and the other one (`LinearLayout`) has 8/10, as I saw in the preview of my IDE (Android Studio), the `RelativeLayout` is the bigger one here's my question:

The `layout_weight` with less value will be the bigger one?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html):

> A larger weight value allows it to expand to fill any remaining space in the parent view

The key part here is **"remaining space"**

This means that if the `RelativeLayout` height is bigger them half of its parent height, it will be bigger then the `LinearLayout` no matter to what  value you set its `android:layout_weight` property

Answer (score 1):

No, the larger value for `layout_weight` should be the bigger one.
When using `layout_weight` you should set either the height or width to 0dp; in a vertical layout you're dealing with height and in a horizontal one it's width.

So in your case your root layout is a vertical LinearLayout. Within that, your relative layout with a weight of '2' should have `android:layout_height="0dp"` and the same for your LinearLayout with a weight of '8'.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like this: (top takes up 20% bottom takes up 80%)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:weightSum="5"
   android:orientation="vertical">

<!--  Specify height as 0dp-->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/centerText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:text="HALLO ALLE"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/centerText"
        android:text="Button top"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Specify height as 0dp -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Btn 1"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

When dealing with layout weights you supply 0dp to the layout width or height of the weighted item when parents orientation is horizontal or vertical.

Answer (score 0):

When ever using weights it is better to use corresponding one to 0dp and then use the layout_weight....like

In Case of `android:orientation="horizontal"`

Use the following code

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

In Case of `android:orientation="vertical"`

Use the following code

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```